# Performing a polar transformation on an image in reverse clock direction using scikit-image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

As the following experiment shows, the `warp_polar` function of the [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.16.x/auto_examples/transform/plot_register_rotation.html) library performs the polar transformation in clock direction. However, I want to perform a polar transformation in the **reverse clock direction**. I should probably flip or rotate the image in some way to achieve the desired end result. However, I am not sure how to do this. I would appreciate any efficient solution.

In a correct solution, the transformed image would have the following sequence of numbers: 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10....

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from skimage.transform import warp_polar
import cv2

testImg = cv2.cvtColor(mpimg.imread('clock.png'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
pol = warp_polar(testImg, radius=min(testImg.shape)/2)

# Create 2x2 sub plots
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0]) # row 0, col 0
ax1.imshow(testImg)
ax1.set_title("Original Image")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1]) # row 0, col 1
ax2.imshow(pol)
ax2.set_title("Polar Transformation")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: changing direction of polar warp would just flip the resulting image vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, I found out that the solution was much simpler than I thought. Flipping the result of `warp_polar` vertically is equivalent to applying the polar transformation in the reverse clock direction.

```
import numpy as np
pol = np.flip(pol,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could flip the image on axis prior to input, then run your current polar warp to get the result like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from skimage.transform import warp_polar
import cv2

testImg = cv2.cvtColor(mpimg.imread('clock.png'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
horizontal_flip = testImg[:, ::-1]
pol = warp_polar(horizontal_flip, radius=min(horizontal_flip.shape)/2)

# Create 2x2 sub plots
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0]) # row 0, col 0
ax1.imshow(horizontal_flip)
ax1.set_title("Original Image")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1]) # row 0, col 1
ax2.imshow(pol)
ax2.set_title("Polar Transformation")

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Comment: No. If I start from 3 and perform a polar transformation in reverse clock direction, the next upcoming number (after 3) would be 2 (as suggested in the question).